# My anchor tag is unclickable when creating a drop-shadow

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML and CSS, creating a big panel with a drop shadow that should be clickable. But it is not. I think it is an issue with Z-indexes and relative positioning, but I can't figure out a way to make it work without losing the drop shadow.

http://jsfiddle.net/ddfAL/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
<div class="drop-shadow"><a href="#">Click</a></div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    padding: 50px;
    z-index: -10;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #bbb;
}

a {
    display: block;
    padding: 50px;
}

.drop-shadow {
  position: relative;
  color: #888;
  background: #fdfdfd;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 5px #f3f0e9, inset 0 0 13px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 5px #f3f0e9, inset 0 0 13px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  -o-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 5px #f3f0e9, inset 0 0 13px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 5px #f3f0e9, inset 0 0 13px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}


.drop-shadow:before, .drop-shadow:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 5px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20%;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -o-box-shadow: 0 15px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0 15px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
}

.drop-shadow:after {
  right: 5px;
  left: auto;
  -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(3deg);
  transform: rotate(3deg);
}
```

​

Comment: If you meant to make the whole div clickable - http://jsfiddle.net/ddfAL/2/ - works fine in IE10 on windows 7

Comment: I don't see the difference, and it doesn't work on my Chrome.

Comment: The `z-index:-10` on `#container` is pushing your element under the `<body>`.  Either add `z-index:-11` to the body or restructure this so you're not using negative indexes to avoid these types of conflicts. You'll also need a `position:relative` on the `<body>`

Comment: Yeah the problem is with z-index. Works fine on IE10 on windows 7 but not on Chrome 23. Changing z-index values seems to do the trick. @potench: you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest fix is to add this CSS rule:

```
body {
   position:relative;
   z-index:-11;
}
```

You might consider restructuring your markup to avoid using negative `z-index` because you'll risk micromanaging them (as we've already begun to do by adding a `z-index` to the `<body>`).